# In which scriptures are found the rituals for Sannyasa initiation?

Tags: scripture, rituals, mantras, sannyasa

The Vedas (Samhitas) do not talk about Sannyasa at all, so they won't have them.

The principle Upanishads (13/14 of them) also do not have them, but they do mention the word "Sannyasa".

- Then, in which scriptures are the rituals and Mantras, to be used during initiation into Sannyasa, found?
- Also, what Mantras are used and what is the process in brief?

Comment: the mantras are not given out unless you go through the initiation. The ritualistic portion is done by a brahmin priest. The mantras are given at the end by the sannyas guru after the rituals are done and the gerua cloth has been put on. They are considered sacred and not given out to uninitiated.

Comment: So u don't know which scriptures the rituals are based upon? how can it be so? There has to be some scriptures that provide the guidelines. @SwamiVishwananda

Comment: Reason for the downvotes?

Comment: Word sanyasa and initiation are technically antonyms

Comment: No actually they are not.. See in [this](http://www.kamakoti.org/peeth/origin.html) Kaamkoti page they are using the term Sannyasa Diksha.. and I hv found references in some scriptures too where the word Diksha is used for Sannyasa Grahana. @RakeshJoshi

Comment: @Rickross obviously they will use. But if you see diksha process then you will understand. For example they shave off the shikha and cut off the thread yet claim to be vedic etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Self answering... also a partial answer.*

The process of taking Sannyasa is found in the book called the **"Essence of Dharma Sindhu"** hosted at the Kamakoti.org. But there is no mention of any scriptures from which the guidelines, Mantras etc are taken. Otherwise, the details is quite extensive.

> **Sanyaasa Grahana Vidhi:**
>
> Uttaraayana is stated to be the preferred time for initiating into
>   Sanyasa, especially for those who have Grihyaagni. Having located a
>   Sadguru who possesses Shanti and Danti o r Placidity and Self
>   Restraint, the aspirant Sanya si should learn Sanyasi Dharmas from the
>   tutelage and keep on practising Gayatri Japa, Rudra Japa and
>   Kushmanda Homa for three months and after attai ning Bahyaantara
>   Shuchi on one Rikta Tithi make th e Sankalpa: *Amukasya Mama karishya
>   -maana Sanyaase neydhikaaraartham Chatuh krucchaatmakam praayaschi ttam Pratikruccham tatprachyamnaayaika Gonishkriya dwaaraaha
>   maacharishye Krucchaprtayaamnaaa Gonishk raya dravyam Viprebhyo
>   daatumahamtsrujey/*
>
> Thus hav ing given Go-Pratyaamnaaya,commence series of Shra addhas on
>   Ekadashi or Dwadashi at Brahma Ratri. As hramasastha has to perform
>   ChatuhKruccha followed by Ashta Shraddhas; Aapastambas and
>   Hiranyakeshiya s follow the Saankalpa Vidhi without Agnoukarana P
>   indaas and by Sankalpa Vidhi only. But Ashwalaayan aadis follow
>   Sapinda Paravana Prayoga; in this in Savya position they perform
>   Shraddhaanga Tarpana with Yava mishra jala in rivers and waterflows
>   sta ting: *Brahmaanam Tarpayaami, Vishnum--; Maheshwara m--;
>   Devarsheen--; Brahmarsheen--;Kshatrarsheen--;
>   Vasoon--;Rudraan--;Adityaan--; Sanakam--;Sanandan am--;
>   Sanaatanam--;Pancha Maha Bhutaani--; Chakshu raadi
>   Karanaani--;Bhutagraamam--; Pitaram--; Pitaa maham--;Prapitaamaham--;
>   Aatmaanam-/*
>
> Having return ed home the Karta would then announce Desha Kaalaa di
>   and make the Sankalpa: *Karishyamaana Sanyaaasaa ngatvey noushtaa
>   shraadhhani paarvana vidhinaannen aameynavaa karishye*/
>
> This would be like Naandi Shr aaddha and hence in Savya position
>   itself by using yavaas in place of Tilas. The opening Shraaddha is
>   meant for Satya Vasu Sanjnika Vishwa Devas involv ing two Naandi Mukha
>   Brahmanaas and naming (Vaana) of one of them to organise the Eight
>   Shraaddhas. In the Prathama Deva Shraaddha, the ‘Ucchaarana’ or
>   recital would be Brahma Vishnu Maheshwaraa Naan di Mukhaah
>   Sthaanekshanah priyataam/ The Second one is Rishi Shraaddha with the
>   Uccharana of Deve shi Brahmarshi Kshatrarshi yo naandi –mukhaah Stha
>   anekshana priyataam/ The third one is Divya Shradd ha addressed to
>   Vasu Rudraa- ditya Rupaa naandhi mukhaaya--/ The fourth one is
>   Manushya Shraddha to Sanaka Sanandana Sanaatanaadi----; the fifth one
>   is Bhuta Shraaddha to Prithivyaadi pancha Mahaa bh utaan –yekaadasha
>   chakshuraadi karanaadi chaturvid ha bhutagraamaa naandi mukha;the
>   sixth one is Pitr a Shraaddha to Pitru Pitaamaha Prapitaamahi naandi
>   mukha----; the Seventh Shraaddha is directed to M aatru Pitaamahi
>   Prapitaamahyo naandi mukha---; and finally the Eighth Shraaddha being
>   Atma Shraaddha and the Uccharana is: Atmaantaraatma Paramaatmaa nah
>   Naandi mukha----. After the Naandimukha, Padya is given to Vishwa De
>   vas with the Mantra : *Sanyaasaartha maham Shraaddh am kurvey bruta
>   Dwijottamaah, Anugnaam praapya ush maakam siddhim praapyaami
>   shasvateem/*
>
> Then one Vishwa Deva Patra and Ashta Patras for are arranged for
>   Deva-Rishi-Divya-Manushya-Bhuta-Pitru-MaatruAtma to provide
>   Aasana-Gandhaadi Ahutis are offere d. This method is by way of
>   Sankalpa in the case of Apastambaas but Ashvaayanas perform with
>   ‘Arghy apaatraa- sadana’. Pinda-daanaadikas also are not applicable to
>   Apastambaas. After the Ashta Shraddh a on the first day, the Sanyasa
>   Karmas on the foll owing day include kesha khandana , Nadi Snaana, ko
>   upeena dharana, danda dharana, kamandalu dharana, Achhadana Vastra
>   dhaaranaadi karmas. **Then the Sanyasa Grahana Karya is followed by
>   the Maha Sankalpa** : *Asesha duhkha nivrutti niratishaya -ananda pra
>   apti rupa Parama Purushaartha praaptaye Parama Ham sa Sanyaasa
>   grahanam karishye/ Tadangatayaa Ganapa ti pujana punyaahvachana
>   Maatrukaa pujana Naandhi Shraaddhaani karishye/*
>
> The procedure is as follows : Recite the Mantra viz. *Brahmaney namah,
>   Vishna vey namah, Rudraaya namah, Suryaaya, Somaaya, Atm aney,
>   Antaratmaney, Agnimeeley, Ishetvorjetwaa, Ag na Aayaahi Shannodevi
>   etc.*; take three fistfuls of ‘Satthu Pishta’ or mix of cereals,
>   millets and pu lses, eat the Sattu thrice and touch the naabhi ;
>   recite again the Mantra: Atmaney swaha Antaraatma ney swaaha
>   Paramatmaney Prajaapataye swaaha; eat the mix of milk-curd-ghee-water
>   by the Mantras of t rivridasi once, pravridasi twice, divrudasi thrice
>   , then drink water saying Aapah punantu and finally state: Upavaasam
>   karishye/

Thereafter, in that order, are to be performed the following rituals:

**Savitri Pravesha**

> The Karta would recite : *Om Bhuh Savitrim pravishaami; Om Tat
>   Savaturvarenyam Om B huvah Savitrim pravishaami; Bhargodevasya dheemah
>   i; Om Swaha Savitrim pravishaami; Dhiyoyonah prach odayat Om
>   Bhurbhuvaswah Savitrim praveshayaami; Ta tsavatur varenyam Bhargo
>   Devasya dheemahi dhiyoyon ah prachodayat*/

**Viraja Homa**

> This is a highlight Homa in the conte xt of Sanyasa Grahana Vidhana
>   and is more or less the conclusive component of the Vidhana. Vira ja
>   Mantra : It is with this Mantra that forty clim actic Ahutis to
>   Agnideva are executed with a wide variety of Dravyas

**Sarva Tyaga Vidhi:**

> Total Renunciation starts with the recital of the Maasa-Tithi-kaalas
>   by the Karta as he would leave three handfuls of water in a
>   Jalaashaya : *Aparoksha Brahmaavaaptaye Sanyaasam Karomi/--Yeshahavaa
>   Agnissurayah praanam gacchasw aa, Om swaamyonimgaccha swaahaa/*
>   Viraja Homa

and finally, the **Praisocchara**:

> Praishocchaara: The terminal acts of Sanyasa Vidha ana of
>   Praishocchaara of the new Sanyasi are as f ollows: First with leaving
>   water in the Flow with the Mantras thrice in three tones of low-medium
>   an d loud voice: *Om Bhuh Samnyastam mayaa, Om Bhuvah Samnyastam
>   mayaa, Om Swaha Samnyastam mayaa, Om B hurbhuvaswah Samnyastam mayaa/*
>   Then the Shikha is unfurled and cut; the Yagnopaveeta is taken out b y
>   the raise of his hands above the shoulders and k ept in his hands
>   reciting the Mantra:

For all these above processes, i have omitted a huge amount of actual details, because otherwise, it makes the answer exceptionally long.

Those who want to read in details can read [this chapter of the book "Essence of Dharma Sindhu"](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/dharmasindhu/bookview.php?chapnum=26)

But, i am interested to know from which scriptures all these Mantras and procedures are taken. So, that part of the question is yet to be answered.

Comment: from my direct experience your answer is not correct.

Comment: You can at most say that the method which was followed in ur case was not this one..but that does not mean that my answer is incorrect.. it isn't @SwamiVishwananda

Comment: Reason for the downvotes?

Answer (score 3):

This is a partial answer.

Mantras for dasnami sannyasis are the four maha vakyas of the Upanishads. The mantra of the Puri Dasnami Sannyasis to which Ramakrishna Order belongs is

> Ayamatma Brahma

Mandukya Upanishad 2

This is what I was told by Swami Sarvadevananda.

Comment: I have asked what are the mantras and the rituals.. just one mantra and the ritual is over?.. what are the mantras for example with which the sikha is cut? the upavita is sacrificed? i am looking for such information..

Comment: I have given what Swami Sarvadevananda told us when I was attending his lectures on Pancadasi. I thought that this was an important piece of information to share with the readers.  I did state at the very beginning, just like your did, that mine is a partial answer.

Comment: Well i was looking for the full process that happens during the ritual including the mantras that are used. So, it's good that u have added ur answer but it's not of much use for my purpose..

Comment: This is not secret and common knowledge that one of the Mahavakyas is used for Dasmani sannyas and the Puri is the one you quoted.

Comment: If Viraja Homa does not happen then that person has not become a Sannyasi. No wonder such faulty rituals are practiced in Kali Yuga and the effects are for everyone to see. @PradipGangopadhyay

Comment: @Rickross, I don't think fault in rituals matters. What matters is the state of the person's mind. Valmiki became a saint by repeating mara.

Comment: Rituals are flawed nowadays. That's a fact I have verified. And that's how Hindus have become so poor, weak, diseased and lacking in virility.. so many people chant so many mantras but nothing happens because the first rite (initiation) itself is flawed. @PradipGangopadhyay